# Livereload of .html pages - Gulp

Tags: gulp, livereload

I have got this code so far, but it does not work.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
    connect.server({
      livereload: true
    });
});



gulp.task('default', ['webserver']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify file path to watch look this :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: 'app',
    livereload: true
  });
});

gulp.task('html', function () {
  gulp.src('./app/*.html')
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(['./app/*.html'], ['html']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'watch']);
```